# How to reread Kafka topic from the beginning

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

I have Spring Boot app that uses Kafka via Spring Kafka module. A neighboring team sends data in JSON format periodically to a compacted topic that serves as "snapshot" of their internal database at a certain moment of time. But,sometimes, the team updates contract without notification, our DTOs don't reflect the recent changes and, obviously, deserialization fails, and, because we have our listener containers configured as batched with default BATCH ack mode and BatchLoggingErrorHandler, we found, from time to time, that our Kuber pod with consumer is full of errors and we can't reread topic with fresh DTOs after microservice redeploy that simple since the last offset in every partition is commited and we can't change *group.id* (InfoSec department policy) to use *auto.offset.reset = "earliest"* as a workaround.
So, is there a way to reposition every consumer in a consumer group to the initial offset in assigned partitions programmaticaly? If it is true, I think we could write a REST endpoint, which being called triggers a "reprocessing from scratch".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#seek).

If your listener extends `AbstractConsumerSeekAware`, you can perform all kinds of seek operations (e.g. initial seek during initialization, arbitrary seeks between polls).